# Imported library doesn't build in Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, cmake

I try to add a imported library to my project, and link it to another Library.

Here is some part of my code from  CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(native-lib SHARED ${sources})

add_library(imported-lib SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(imported-lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/PathToLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/imported-lib.so)
```

In my native-lib, I create an object of a Class which is placed in imported-lib but the app starts crash. (if I debug or run the app then make project works fine)

In the Gradle Console i get an Info: [org.gradle.api.Task] externalNativeBuildDebug: not building target imported-lib because there was no build command for it

How can I build it?

Comment: Looking into error message it seems that *somewhere in your code* there is `imported-lib` defined as normal library (not imported). Please, provide [mcve].

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your Answer. No there is no other library with that name. This is what Logcat say: "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol"

Comment: Hm, another reason could be that *IMPORTED_LOCATION* property points to non-existent file. BTW, variable `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` is mostly for *included* CMake scripts (`*.cmake`); `CMakeLists.txt` usually uses `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` variable.

Comment: I think I know whats wrong, but I don´t know why. If I add the library, it is shown in the Project Structure. But if I build the App, the library is not under /outputs/apk/lib.

Comment: So, the problem is with imported library and its installation, but not with the your code. Am I right with such interpretation of your last comment? If so, currently formulated question has no sence.

Comment: Not sure it's your problem but I solved mine by making sure the library was in `/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}` (the exact location seem to be important)

Answer (score 1):

The shared lib currently need to packed into apk manually, one way is to route jniLibs to your shared lib directory. Hope later version could pack it automatically. One example is here,https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs, it imports one shared lib, one static lib; shared lib is packed to APK  with script in app/build.gradle:jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../distribution/gperf/lib']

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for me is so in the build.gradle. The 'make' must be in PATH.

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
    ...
        arguments "-GAndroid Gradle - Unix Makefiles",
                  "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=make"
    }
}
```